# Under what circumstances can I drop 'I' used as a subject?

Tags: grammar

Under what circumstances can I drop 'I' used as a subject? For example, Nina Simone sang 'Ain't got no money, ain't got no clothes' and so forth. I was wondering whether I could do the same and under what conditions. My current understanding is that in, at least, Past Simple and Present Perfect sentences it's ok (albeit informal).

Comment: Only in a _very_ informal context! The fact that the song uses _ain't_ shows that it is in an extremely informal register (instead of _I haven't got any money_ or _I have no money_).

Comment: Maybe not necessarily *only* super informal contexts. I can imagine an example from a work environment. It seems to work the best with negative phrases in the past. For example:

A: Were you able to finish the project? 
B: So sorry, haven't had a single moment free until now. I'll get to work.

The subject is obviously implied, most importantly by the question.

Comment: There seems to be something about really just eliminating the first *syllable* of a sentence if it isn't stressed, in certain contexts. Going to think more on this and try to come up with the best examples.

Comment: @TedPal and how about "Woke up this morning, got out of bed" as another example but not negative?

Comment: @mdewey: Exactly. As a response to the question: "What are you up to today?"